# Implement Endpoint for file upload (API gateway + Lambda + Python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

How and what’s to be configured in API gateway to accept file as an input in AJAX call. Also How to read the contents of the file in Python Lambda?
There ain't much help with examples available in the official aws docs

Comment: I want to upload a doc/docx file from the client and then parse and convert into JSON data and return it back to the client

Answer (score 1):

We need to zip the dependencies along with python file and upload it.

For example if you wish to read a file called `input.conf` in python file `reader.py`,
you need to create a zip file which includes the above files within it.

```
/uploader.zip
  |- input.conf
  | - reader.py
```

The name of the python file should be the first part of lambda handler, like:
`reader.lambda_handler` (in case of python)

Comment: refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html for more details

Comment: I want to upload the file from the browser and user's gonna provide this file.

Comment: In that case, you need to read the file as bytes (for binary file) or string and add it to request body which will be passed to api gateway.

Comment: File cannot be passed directly to api gateway (REST accepts payload only as string in json or xml). You should be reading the file from client side and sent it to server as string in the request payload

Comment: That's my exact question on how to do that?

Comment: The contents of the file needs to be passed as string or bytes (depending on if its a text file or a binary file)